# Which thing is better and efficient for data display using AJAX Full template or JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am new to jquery and JSON and i am bit confused as what is best and professional approach.

Suppose i have the long list of data like song name , artist , author etc.

Now i dynamically want to dislay records from database.

I have two options

1. Here i return the full html and update that with  the target element
2. Second is to retrive the JSON data full of songs info and then build that html with javascript and populate it.

I want to know which approach is better and used by high traffic sites

Answer (score 0):

Second is better because of data size being sent over the network. Reducing it will improve the performance.
Write a function that will use JSON data to generate HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a high traffic site with lots of data then the second solution, using JSON does have the advantage of only giving you the raw data and relying on the browser to generate the HTML to display the data.

Personally I would need to hear some really convincing arguments for using the first option at all.